# Don't understand error thrown by Soap call

Tags: php, soap

I'm attempting to use freightquote.com's API.  To do this I am using a class that extends SOAP which you can see [here](http://pastie.org/8165331) <--cudos to the author.  The code that I am using to make the call can be found below

```
$this->load->library('QuoteService');
    try
    {
        $client = new QuoteService();

        $user = new UserCredential();
        $user->Name = 'example@example.com';
        $user->Password = 'password';

        $add = new PostalAddress();
        $add->AddressName = 'home';
        $add->City = 'Fond du Lac';
        $add->PostalCode = '54922';
        $add->StateCode = 'WI';
        $add->StreetAddress = 'W4709 Main St.';
        $add->CountryCode = 'US';           

        $loc = new Location();
        $loc->HasLoadingDock = 1;
        $loc2->LocationType = LocationTypeList::Origin;
        $loc->HasDeliveryAppointment = 1;
        $loc->LocationAddress = $add;

        $add2 = new PostalAddress();
        $add2->AddressName = 'dropoff';
        $add2->City = 'Oshkosh';
        $add2->PostalCode = '54901';
        $add2->StateCode = 'WI';
        $add2->StreetAddress = '424 Washington Ave.';
        $add2->CountryCode = 'US';


        $loc2 = new Location();
        $loc2->LocationType = LocationTypeList::Destination;
        $loc2->HasDeliveryAppointment = 1;
        $loc2->LocationAddress = $add2;
        // comment
        $prod = new Product();
        $prod->IsHazardousMaterial = 0;
        $prod->Length = 50;
        $prod->Width = 50;
        $prod->Height = 50;
        $prod->PieceCount = 10;
        $prod->ProductDescription = "Stones";
        $prod->PackageType = 'unknown';


        $ship = new Shipment();
        $ship->PickupDate = '2010-09-13T00:00:00';
        $ship->ShipmentLocations = array($add,$add2);
        $ship->IsBlind = 0;
        $ship->ShipmentProducts = array($prod);



        $quote_request = new QuoteRequest();
        $quote_request->QuoteType = QuoteTypeList::B2B;
        $quote_request->ServiceType = ServiceTypeList::Truckload;
        $quote_request->QuoteShipment = $ship;
        $quote_request->CustomerId = 0;

        $request = new GetRatingEngineQuote();
        $request->request = $quote_request;
        $request->user = $user;

        $response = $client->GetRatingEngineQuote($request);
```

When I attempt to run this code I get the following error

> Soap fault System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to read request. >---> System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (2, 458). ---> >System.FormatException: The string '' is not a valid Boolean value. at >System.Xml.XmlConvert.ToBoolean(String s) at >Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReader1.Read15_Shipment(Bool>ean isNullable, Boolean checkType) at >Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReader1.Read17_QuoteRequest(>Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType) at >Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReader1.Read42_GetRatingEngi>neQuote() at >Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.ArrayOfObjectSerializer.Deserialize(XmlSeria>lizationReader reader) at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader >xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events) --- End of inner >exception stack trace --- at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader >xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events) at >System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String >encodingStyle) at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.ReadParameters() --- >End of inner exception stack trace --- at >System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.ReadParameters() at >System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()

I'm having difficulty figuring out exactly whether the error means that it is missing a required parameter or simply receiving the wrong datatype.  Any assistance with methods of troubleshooting, what the error means exactly, or even a solution would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: is it `$shipment->isBlind = 1` try setting it to `true`

Comment: Tried variations of true/false/ numbers.... no effect

Comment: http://www.spinics.net/lists/phpsoap/msg01214.html

Comment: I get what you're saying, but I've tried true/false and get the same results

Comment: Check the api docs, this might mean that you didn't fill a mandatory field that has type boolean and is, because it's not set, interpreted as an empty string ''. Had the exact same problem...

Answer (score 0):

Can you change

```
$response = $client->GetRatingEngineQuote($request);
```

to

```
try {
    $response = $client->GetRatingEngineQuote($request);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    var_dump($client->__getLastRequest());
}
```

and either provide the output or go to second line to character 458 and check.

Method $client->__getLastRequest() require that client is created with option trace=>true.